# how to keep processing output window always on top

Tags: kinect, processing, simple-openni

I am currently making a project on kinect using SimpleOpenNI and Processing and am new to it.
I want to know how I can keep my output window always on top...even when i switch focus to some other application like powerpoint or vlc??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);`. It's from the `Window` Class, but processing's `frame` variable is an `AWT Frame`, which extends `Window`.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29)